# How does vowpal wabbit works with gradient descend algorithm?

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I have been trying to understand vowpal wabbit algorithm.
Is anyone can help me to understand VW and how to implement it

Answer (score 2):

[Vowpal Wabbit](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit) is focused on online learning (though it can do also batch L-BFGS) and it's main algorithm is [Stochastic gradient descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) with several (optional, but included in the default) improvements (adaptive, normalized updates, clever importance weighting,...).
The algorithm is described on slides 5 and 11 of the [tutorial](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/v6.1_tutorial.pdf).

There is no need to implement it, it's already implemented:-) and it's super fast and memory efficient. Therefore, the code contains many optimization tricks, so it's not really suitable for inspection by beginners.

Comment: Are there any other easy to understand implementation that performs online learning with SGD similar to VW?